# Is there a dependency when declaring a variable in a narrower scope?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, scope

I has two variants of the same code:

A:

```
int i;
while (some condition) {some code}
```

B:

```
while (some condition) {
  int i;
  some code
}
```

Is there some differences in efficiency between A and B? Except fact that we has some free bytes after the `while` scope in B.

How does the memory model work when creating a new scope?

Comment: Some links to read: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-philosophy, http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es5-keep-scopes-small, http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es6-declare-names-in-for-statement-initializers-and-conditions-to-limit-scope. It is mainly about readability, and B makes sure that ressources are freed as early as possible (in case i is not an int but an object). More to consider (in the same guideline): ES.21, ES.22, ES.26.